# Copy Row and add value, VBA

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I am using the following script to copy data to a new sheet, it copies a row a certain number of times, based on a columns data.

I need to add a line to the script to: add the value "Word" into column "M" and the current row that is being copied.

Any help adding this to the script will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

```
Public Sub CopyData()
    ' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
    Dim rngSinglecell As Range
    Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
    Dim intCount As Integer

    ' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
    Set rngQuantityCells = Range("K2", Range("K2").End(xlDown))

    For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells
        ' Check if this cell actually contains a number
        If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell.Value) Then
            ' Check if the number is greater than 0
            If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then
                ' Copy this row as many times as .value
                For intCount = 1 To rngSinglecell.Value
                    ' Copy the row into the next emtpy row in sheet2


                    'Change EntireRow.Copy to a range in the row.
                    Range(rngSinglecell.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    ' The above line finds the next empty row.


                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could:

- use `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object to loop through numeric values of a range
- use `Resize()` property of `Range` Object to avoid paste looping

as follows:

```
Public Sub CopyData()
    ' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
    Dim rngSinglecell As Range
    Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
    Dim intCount As Long

    ' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
    Set rngQuantityCells = Range("K2", Range("K2").End(xlDown))
    If WorksheetFunction.Count(rngQuantityCells) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' do nothing if no numbers in wanted range

    For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) ' loop through numeric values of wanted range
        ' Check if the number is greater than 0
        If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then
            Range(rngSinglecell.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell.Value)
            Cells(rngSinglecell.Row, "M").Value = "Word" ' <-- added line
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```